# Hide tabs on all pages

Tags: blocks

On every page on my site, there are always these tabs on display:

> News, Events, Grant.

I have been able to hide them on specific pages using CSS Injector however I want to disable these tabs from appearing.

How can I do this?

I have added a screenshot for reference:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please add screenshot here instead of adding link. I see some porn images there (may be ads).That would be too bad for your post. Sometimes may consider your post as SPAM :) I can't dare to open that ilnk again and paste that image here for you :)

Comment: I tried adding the image here in not allowed.

Comment: Don't add image from the web (from link). upload that image from your computer instead.

Comment: Do the tabs persist if you log out of the site? They seem like standard tabs for administrative users who have relevant permissions. If they appear then you're logged out then I'd wager your issue is actually with permissions and not the tabs displaying.

Comment: I agree with the above comment by Chapabu. But if you really want to hide them do it with css or your page.tpl.php ($tabs)

Answer (score 0):

Are those tabs menu entries? Check the menus you have listed in `structure > menus`. I'm not sure what menu it would be in because it may depend on the theme so click through them all.

Those could also be potentially generated by a View so check entries in `structure > views` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Tab Tammer](https://www.drupal.org/project/tabtamer) module

> Tab Tamer is an administration utility that provides easy re-ordering, hiding, and deactivation of tabs and subtabs. You can also rename tab labels.